How to Filter Products Based on Quantity Used in Laravel Modal for Interventions?
I am working on a Laravel application that manages interventions and tracks the usage of products. I have three related tables:

sorties_approuvees (approved product exits)

interventions

intervention_sortie_approuvee (pivot table linking interventions to approved product exits)


I want if the user wants to add a new intervention, not to display in the list of products those where the quantity used is equal to quantity. And if he wants to modify an intervention, display the products where the quantity is greater than the quantity used but also those which are associated with the intervention even if the quantity used is equal to the quantity.
All my forms are displayed in modal form using a button.
Schema::create('sorties_approuvees', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('designation');
            $table->string('marque');
            $table->integer('quantite');
            $table->integer('quantite_utilisee')->default(0);
            $table->integer('prix_unitaire');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('produit_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('idcat');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('id_storage');
            $table->foreign('produit_id')->references('id')->on('sorties');
            $table->foreign('idcat')->references('id')->on('categories');
            $table->foreign('id_storage')->references('id')->on('storages');
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Schema::create('interventions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->text('description');
            $table->date('date_debut');
            $table->date('date_fin');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('demande_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('technicien_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('Num_Depart');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('Num_Service');
            $table->foreign('demande_id')->references('id')->on('demandes_maintenances');
            $table->foreign('technicien_id')->references('id')->on('techniciens');
            $table->foreign('Num_Depart')->references('Num_Depart')->on('departements');
            $table->foreign('Num_Service')->references('Num_Service')->on('services');
            $table->string('statut')->default('en attente');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Schema::create('intervention_sortie_approuvee', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('intervention_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('sortie_approuvee_id');
            $table->foreign('intervention_id')->references('id')->on('interventions')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('sortie_approuvee_id')->references('id')->on('sorties_approuvees')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->integer('quantite')->default(0);
            $table->integer('prix_unitaire')->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Button edit:
<button class="edit-btn" 
                                    data-id="{{$intervention->id}}" 
                                    data-description="{{$intervention->description}}" 
                                    data-date_debut="{{$intervention->date_debut}}" 
                                    data-date_fin="{{$intervention->date_fin}}"
                                    data-pieces="{{ json_encode($intervention->sortieApprouvee->map(function($produit) {
                                                        return [
                                                            'stock_id' => $produit->id,
                                                            'quantite' => $produit->pivot->quantite,
                                                            'designation' => $produit->designation
                                                        ];
                                                    })) }}"
                                    data-demande="{{$intervention->demande_id}}"
                                    data-technicien="{{$intervention->technicien_id}}" 
                                    data-departement="{{$intervention->Num_Depart}}"
                                    data-service="{{$intervention->Num_Service}}"
                                    data-statut="{{ $intervention->statut }}"><i class='bx bxs-edit-alt' ></i></button>

Script:
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const modal = document.getElementById('editModal');

    document.querySelectorAll('.edit-btn').forEach(function(button) {
        button.addEventListener('click', function() {
            const interventionID = this.getAttribute('data-id');
            const interventionDescription = this.getAttribute('data-description');
            const interventionDateDebut = this.getAttribute('data-date_debut'); 
            const interventionDateFin = this.getAttribute('data-date_fin');
            const interventionPieces = JSON.parse(this.getAttribute('data-pieces'));
            const interventionDemande = this.getAttribute('data-demande');
            const interventionTechnicien = this.getAttribute('data-technicien');
            const interventionDepartement = this.getAttribute('data-departement');
            const interventionService = this.getAttribute('data-service');
            const interventionStatut = this.getAttribute('data-statut');

            // Stocker les pièces pour accès dans d'autres scripts
            window.interventionPieces = JSON.parse(this.getAttribute('data-pieces'));

            console.log('interventionID:', interventionID);
            console.log('interventionDescription:', interventionDescription);
            console.log('interventionDateDebut:', interventionDateDebut);
            console.log('interventionDateFin:', interventionDateFin);
            console.log('interventionPieces:', interventionPieces);
            console.log('interventionDemande:', interventionDemande);
            console.log('interventionTechnicien:', interventionTechnicien);
            console.log('interventionDepartement:', interventionDepartement);
            console.log('interventionStatut:', interventionStatut);

            // Remplir les champs du formulaire avec les données de l'intervention
            document.getElementById('edit-interventionId').value = interventionID;
            document.getElementById('edit-description').value = interventionDescription;
            document.getElementById('edit-date_debut').value = interventionDateDebut;
            document.getElementById('edit-date_fin').value = interventionDateFin;
            document.getElementById('edit-demande').value = interventionDemande;
            document.getElementById('edit-technicien').value = interventionTechnicien;
            document.getElementById('edit-departement').value = interventionDepartement;

            // Update the statut select field
            const statutElement = document.getElementById('edit-statut');
            if (statutElement) {
                statutElement.value = interventionStatut || '';  // Set it to the fetched status or empty if none
            } else {
                console.error("Element with ID 'edit-statut' not found");
            }

            // Vider les lignes existantes du tableau
            const tableBody = document.getElementById('pieces-table-body');
            tableBody.innerHTML = '';

            // Remplir le tableau avec les pièces et quantités
            interventionPieces.forEach(function(piece) {
                // Ne rien faire si le stock_id est 0 ou si la quantité est 0
                if (piece.stock_id != 0 && piece.quantite != 0) {
                    const row = document.createElement('tr');

                    const designationCell = document.createElement('td');
                    designationCell.textContent = piece.designation;

                    const quantityCell = document.createElement('td');
                    const quantityInput = document.createElement('input');
                    quantityInput.type = 'number';
                    quantityInput.name = 'quantities[]';
                    quantityInput.value = piece.quantite;
                    quantityCell.appendChild(quantityInput);

                    const hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
                    hiddenInput.type = 'hidden';
                    hiddenInput.name = 'pieces[]';
                    hiddenInput.value = piece.stock_id;

                    const hiddenCell = document.createElement('td');
                    hiddenCell.appendChild(hiddenInput);
                    hiddenCell.style.display = 'none';

                    row.appendChild(designationCell);
                    row.appendChild(quantityCell);
                    row.appendChild(hiddenCell);

                    tableBody.appendChild(row);
                }
            });

            // Récupérer les services pour le département sélectionné
            fetch('/getServicesByDepartement/' + interventionDepartement)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                var serviceSelect = document.getElementById('edit-service');
                serviceSelect.innerHTML = '<option value="">Choisir</option>';
                
                data.forEach(function(service) {
                    var option = document.createElement('option');
                    option.value = service.Num_Service;
                    option.textContent = service.Libellé_Service;
                    serviceSelect.appendChild(option);
                });

                // Sélectionner le service actuel après avoir rempli les options
                document.getElementById('edit-service').value = interventionService;
            });

            const form = document.querySelector('.custom-form');
            form.action = form.action.replace('edit/', 'edit/' + interventionID);

            modal.style.display = 'block';
        });
    });

    document.getElementById('edit-departement').addEventListener('change', function() {
        var departementId = this.value;
        
        if (departementId) {
            fetch('/getServicesByDepartement/' + departementId)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    var serviceSelect = document.getElementById('edit-service');
                    serviceSelect.innerHTML = '<option value="">Choisir</option>';
                    
                    data.forEach(function(service) {
                        var option = document.createElement('option');
                        option.value = service.Num_Service;
                        option.textContent = service.Libellé_Service;
                        serviceSelect.appendChild(option);
                    });
                });
        } else {
            document.getElementById('edit-service').innerHTML = '<option value="">Choisir</option>';
        }
    });
});

<div id="editModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <div class="form-container">
            <form class="custom-form" method="POST" action="{{ route('updateIntervention') }}">
                @csrf
                <h2>Modifier Intervention</h2>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" id="edit-interventionId">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="hidden" id="edit-demande" name="demande" readonly>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="description">Description:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="edit-description" name="description" required>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="date_debut">Date de Début:</label>
                    <input type="date" id="edit-date_debut" name="date_debut" required>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="date_fin">Date de Fin:</label>
                    <input type="date" id="edit-date_fin" name="date_fin" required>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Ajouter des pièces utilisées ?</label><br>
                    <input type="radio" id="edit-oui" name="pieces_utilisees" value="oui">
                    <label for="edit-oui">Oui</label><br>
                    <input type="radio" id="edit-non" name="pieces_utilisees" value="non" checked>
                    <label for="edit-non">Non</label>
                </div>

                <table id="pieces-table" class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Designation</th>
                            <th>Quantity</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="pieces-table-body">
                        <!-- Rows will be dynamically added here -->
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="technicien">Technicien:</label>
                    <select id="edit-technicien" name="technicien" style="width:100%;" required>
                        <option value="">Choisir</option>
                        @foreach($techniciens as $technicien)
                            <option value="{{ $technicien->id }}">{{ $technicien->Nom }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="departement">Département:</label>
                    <select id="edit-departement" name="departement" style="width:100%;" required>
                        <option value="">Choisir</option>
                        @foreach($departements as $departement)
                            <option value="{{ $departement->Num_Depart }}">{{ $departement->Libellé_Depart }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="service">Service:</label>
                    <select id="edit-service" name="service" style="width:100%;" required>
                        <option value="">Choisir</option>
                        @foreach($services as $service)
                            <option value="{{ $service->Num_Service }}">{{ $service->Libellé_Service }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
                @if(auth()->user()->role->name ==='admin')
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="statut">Statut:</label>
                    <select id="edit-statut" name="statut" style="width:100%;">
                        <option value="en attente">En attente</option>
                        <option value="achevee">achevee</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                @endif
                <button type="submit">Save Changes</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

Method index
public function index()
    {
        $interventions = Intervention::with(['demande','departement', 'service', 'technicien', 'sortieApprouvee'])
                            ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
                            ->get();

        // Exclure les demandes avec des interventions achevées
        $demandes = DemandeMaintenance::where('statut', 'planifiee')
        ->whereNotIn('id', function ($query) {
            $query->select('demande_id')
                ->from('interventions')
                ->where('statut', 'achevee');
        })
        ->get();
        
        $departements = Departement::all();
        $services = Service::all();
        $techniciens = Technicien::all();

        // Récupérer tous les produits disponibles ou utilisés
        $produits = SortieApprouvee::where('quantite', '>', 0)
            ->whereColumn('quantite','>','quantite_utilisee')
            ->withTrashed() // Inclure les produits supprimés temporairement
            ->get();

        return view('resp_interv.interventions.allinterventions',[
                    'interventions' => $interventions,
                    'demandes' => $demandes,
                    'departements' => $departements,
                    'services' => $services,
                    'techniciens' => $techniciens,
                    'produits' => $produits,
                ]);
    }

If I have a cable with quantity = 2 and lamp with quantity = 5 and I use the 2 cables and 3 lamps in an intervention. When the user clicks on the add intervention button, display only the lamp and if he wants to modify the intervention or he had already used the cable and the lamps, display both products.
